# yeoman generator runtime dependencies

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm, yeoman, package.json

I'm developing my website which building system has its own yeoman app. There is a yeoman subgenerator, which takes a string parameter from the user, replace the diacritics (language specific chars, such as: ć, ą, ę, ł, ń, ż, ź, etc) with Latin chars (c, a, e, l, n, z, z, etc) and uses it further. I found a suitable node module doing this: https://github.com/andrewrk/node-diacritics.

The question is: which `package.json` should I put the module dependency into? Should it be yeoman-app:`dependencies` (not `devDependencies`, because it's needed during runtime)? Or shall I force yeoman to put it into the website-app:`devDependencies`. What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked it. I should put it into to myCustomYeoman:`dependencies`, because:

- when I run yeoman (sub)generator, it is the generator node.js code which is executed, so installing the dependency to the website module is useless - it has to be installed to the generator.
- all yeoman generators will be eventually installed via `npm install -g <generator-name>`. When installing global modules, npm installs only `dependencies` (and not `devDependencies`). This makes sens, because a globally-installed module is intended to be used, not developed.